# Не работает простой код на Python

Tags: python, re

```
import re

line = 'C:\Users\Persh\Pycharmprojects\Aiogram-Bot-Template\А Как Папу Зовут (6 Секундное Видео  Vine  Вайн  Coub).Mp4'

print(re.sub("C:\Users\Persh\Pycharmprojects\Aiogram-Bot-Template\", line))
```

Почему у меня это не работает? Мне выдает:
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Я пробовал сделать следующим образом:

```
import re

line = 'C:\*Users\Persh\Pycharmprojects\Aiogram-Bot-Template\А Как Папу Зовут (6 Секундное Видео  Vine  Вайн  Coub).Mp4'

print(re.sub('C:\*Users\Persh\Pycharmprojects\Aiogram-Bot-Template\', line))
```

Но теперь у меня почему-то всё превращается в строку и выдает ошибку:
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Не понимаю в чем проблема и что делать,мне нужно убрать определенные символы из строки а конкретнее мне нужно убрать из строки путь к файлу. Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: место `line = '...'` напишите `line = r'...'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Символ `\` в строках вызывает экранирование, например два символа `\n` становятся одним и этот новый символ вызывает перевод на новую строку.

А `\U` является префиксом к описанию юникодного символа формат `\UXXXXXXXX`:

```
line = 'C:\Users\
#        ^^^^^
```

Решением будет использовать raw-строки, где экранирование не вызывается:

```
line = r'C:\Users\Persh\Pycharmprojects\Aiogram-Bot-Template\А Как Папу Зовут (6 Секундное Видео  Vine  Вайн  Coub).Mp4'
```

или экранировать сам `\`:

```
line = 'C:\\Users\\Persh\\Pycharmprojects\\Aiogram-Bot-Template\\А Как Папу Зовут (6 Секундное Видео  Vine  Вайн  Coub).Mp4'
```